# MIP SDK 1.10.97 silently exits with -1073740791

Tags: microsoft-information-protection, mip-sdk

I'm developing an Azure Function for removing information protection from files using the
MIP SDK v. 1.10.97. After some successfull calls to protect or unprotect files the Azure Function silently crashes with code -1073740791.
This did not happen with version 1.9.X.

Any ideas what's happening here?

Thomas